# If/Else statement did not check the input from user

Tags: javascript

I need to code a simple function to check if certain names from user input, redirect to another website. In HTML, I did not use form tag and I use Input and Button tags. When I enter an input start with Anni, it supposed to go to certainwebsite1.com but it went to certainwebsite2.com. I did try to switch around but it still goes to certainwebsite1.

Can anyone spot where I went wrong with my code?

```js
function redirect(){
  var nameInput = document.getElementById('person').value;
 
  if (nameInput == "agnetha" && nameInput == "bjorn" && nameInput == "benny" && nameInput == "anni") {
    window.location = "www.certainwebsite1.com";
  } else {
    window.location = "www.certainwebsite2.com";
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<label for="name">Please enter your name: </label>
<input name="personName" type="text" id="person" value="" />
<button type="button" onclick="redirect()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: a name can't be both agnetha and bjorn at the same time

Comment: `nameInput == '' || nameInput == '' || ...`

Comment: Your condition is wrong, you need to use `||` (OR) instead of `&&` (AND), the input cannot be multiple strings at once

Comment: You are checking if the input value is several names at once. `&&` is the logical-AND operator. Use `||` instead in the line `if (nameInput == "agnetha" && nameInput == "bjorn" && nameInput == "benny" && nameInput == "anni")`

Answer (score 1):

change if statement to this.

```
  if (nameInput == "agnetha" || nameInput == "bjorn" || nameInput == "benny" || nameInput == "anni")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check using `or` condition.

Also make use of `toLowerCase()` and `trim()` function to avoid the case dependency and the space before and after user input in the text field. `toLowerCase` function is because you are trying to compare `Anni` which is the user input with `anni` inside the function.

Also I'm using `window.open` to ensure that the url is opened in a new tab.

```js
function redirect() {
  var nameInput = document.getElementById('person').value.toLowerCase().trim();

  if (nameInput == "agnetha" || nameInput == "bjorn" || nameInput == "benny" || nameInput == "anni") {
    // window.location = "www.certainwebsite1.com";
    window.open("http://www.certainwebsite1.com", "_blank");
  } else {
    // window.location = "www.certainwebsite2.com";
    window.open("http://www.certainwebsite2.com", "_blank");
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<label for="name">Please enter your name: </label>
<input name="personName" type="text" id="person" value="" />
<button type="button" onclick="redirect()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I did try to use | | operator, but when I entered Anni for example, it's still poped up to the second website, not the first website

Comment: @tengkuzulfadli please ensure that you dont have any space before and after 'Anni'. I have updated my answer with `trim` method to to make sure hat the additional spaces are removed.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the input value is several names at once. `&&` is the logical-AND operator. Use `||` instead in the line `if (nameInput == "agnetha" && nameInput == "bjorn" && nameInput == "benny" && nameInput == "anni")`

```js
function redirect(){
  var nameInput = document.getElementById('person').value;
 
  if (nameInput == "agnetha" || nameInput == "bjorn" || nameInput == "benny" || nameInput == "anni") {
    alert("going to www.certainwebsite1.com");
  } else {
    alert("going to www.certainwebsite2.com");
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<label for="name">Please enter your name: </label>
<input name="personName" type="text" id="person" value="" />
<button type="button" onclick="redirect()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did use | | operator as well before I changed to && operator. When I enter the input of Anni for example, it brought me to the second website, not the first website.

Comment: Did you write it in all-lowercase? So `anni` and not `Anni`? To sanitize the input into your program so such errors are not encountered you may wish to use the line `var nameInput = document.getElementById('person').value.toLowerCase();`